# Wordpress проблема с мультиязычностью

Tags: wordpress

Сайт wolf.richgo.ru

Установить плагин Polylang, вроде-бы всё нормально настраивается, но есть проблема. У меня на сайте всего 3 языка (fr, en, de). Все страницы настроены, но у меня не получается открыть английскую версию сайта.

То-есть wolf.richgo.ru/de и wolf.richgo.ru/fr открываются, а если пробую зайти на wolf.richgo.ru/en - неизвестная страница.
Как исправить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Polylang по умолчанию скрывает информацию о языке для языка по умолчанию. Так что ваша ссылка на сайт для английского языка - просто `wolf.richgo.ru`.

Если вы хотите видеть эту ссылке в виде `wolf.richgo.ru/en`, используйте настройки плагина: `Settings->URL modifications`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Стоп, я проверил. У меня и так галочка эта стояла. Если её убрать, всё равно так-же.